# How do I render a 1px gutter between segments with a very small percentage width?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, pocketgrid

I am creating a UI control.  It is a bar which shows colored areas in relative proportion to each other based on the input.  A few of the requirements are that there be a 1px gutter between the colors and that every color must be shown at a minimum of 1px no matter how small the relative width.

The bar looks like this:

[image: colored bar]

The gutters are being placed using a technique described by the [pocketgrid documentation](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#gutters):

```
.threshold-container {
    height: 8px;

    $threshold-horiz-gutter: 1px;

    &.block-group {
        margin-left: -$threshold-horiz-gutter;
    }

    .threshold {
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 2px;

        &.block { 
            padding-left: $threshold-horiz-gutter; 
        }

        .colored-area {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

    }

}
```

There is a codepen here which provides a working example: http://codepen.io/ghoti143/pen/eZNXVW

The problem I face is that when the relative proportion of any one color is sufficiently small, the last color area wraps to the next line and looks like this:

[image]

To replicate this issue, visit the codepen project and enter this as the Threshold Array value:

```
[{"value":0,"color":"LightGreen"},
{"value":50,"color":"PaleGoldenrod"},
{"value":5000,"color":"LightSalmon"},
{"value":10000,"color":"Salmon"}]
```

In this case, the width style of the LightGreen area is 0.33333%.  This equates to 0.495px at a bar width of 150px.  However, because of the requirement to always show at least 1px of width for each color, the LightGreen area is consuming 2px of width (1px content + 1px padding).

Thanks for any insights you may have!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css **calc** function to subtract out the 1px margins from the width calculations for each section. [For example]http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWGNVY

```
coloredAreas.push({
  color: thresholds[i].color,
  width: 'calc(' + width + '% - 1px)'
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion!  The problem here is that in some situations, the bars are too small now (don't take up the whole width of the container).  There are only 3 spacers (3px) but a total of 4px is being subtracted.